# getting ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine('No status line received - the server has closed the connection',)) on python

Tags: python, https, python-requests, connection, wikipedia

I am trying to get data from wikipidia using the wikipidia package which I installed using pip in python.But When I run this code it get this error:

```
raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine('No status line    received - the server has closed the connection',))
```

here's my code:

```
import wikipedia
print(wikipedia.summary('albert einstien',sentences= 3))
```

I have tried to set the wikipedia.API_URL to https instead of http.My code works fine on repl.it(online coding platform) but I get this error when I run this on my pc

Comment: Does using 'Albert Einstein' make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a networking error to me - I recommend to make sure you can reach Wikipedia's API from your browser. If that works, try using the exact page title, ie. "Albert Einstein" in your case.